# Fragment Management - Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a question about fragment management.

I have already programmed a drawer activity based on fragments. After every click on a menu item you will land on an empty fragment.

Now I want to have it so that no matter on which fragment I am on top the same is written. That's about 5 things that are there and depending on the action certain values on the fragment change whatever is there. Like a Information bar.

What options do I have and how do I do that?

Current project scope:

Main activity java + xml
and the Fragments + xml

The main activity is only for the Navigation Drawer. The app starts with a fragment.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

in you main activity just commit which fragment you want to fill that first view with in onCreate.